# Nest for this setup

Tags: wiring, thermostat, nest

[image][image]

Is this the correct wiring setup for nest.

[image]

Comment: That setup looks pretty reasonable to me, but you should double check with Nest.  Enter your information into their compatibility checker to get a proper wiring diagram.  https://nest.com/support/article/How-to-tell-if-your-heating-and-cooling-system-will-work-with-the-Nest-Thermostat#works/?mode=guide

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring at the furnace or air handler?

Comment: I will try and post those tomorrow.  The ac is currently working so I left for it to cool down.  I just wanted to make sure that the jumper from W2 to E on the original diagram was ok for the nest setup.

Comment: I am thinking you really need to put the white wire on W1 and not W2. Your old thermostat had Emergency heat - the Nest will automatically supply this through W1 if I am not mistaken. W2 is Secondary heat or auxiliary - your original already has a Jumper W2 to W1. Your Red Rh wire - depending on system - probably should be connected to Rc - but I could be mistaken here. Your manual should state whether Rc becomes live with 24Vac or Rh. Typically in a T-stat like this if you do not have another Rh red wire, Rc is almost always used .